# mysql join subqueries

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, groupwise-maximum

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `date_time` decimal(26,6) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `connected` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`,`date_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `channel_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `channel_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `channel_name` (`channel_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on how to optimize or rewrite the following query:

```
SELECT channel_name, t0.date_time, t0.value, t0.status, t0.connected, t1.date_time, t1.value, t1.status, t1.connected FROM channels,
    (SELECT MAX(date_time) AS date_time, channel_id, value, status, connected FROM data
        WHERE date_time <= 1300818330
        GROUP BY channel_id) AS t0
    RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(date_time) AS date_time, channel_id, value, status, connected FROM data
        WHERE date_time <= 1300818334
        GROUP BY channel_id) AS t1
ON t0.channel_id = t1.channel_id
WHERE channels.channel_id = t1.channel_id
```

Basically I am getting the value, status and connected fields for each channel_name at two different times. Since t0 is always <= t1, the fields could exist for t1, but not t0, and I want that to be shown. That is why I am using the RIGHT JOIN. If it does not exist for t1, then it won't exist for t0, so no row should be returned.

The problem seems to be that since I am joining sub queries, no index can be used? I tried rewriting it to do a self join on the channel_id of the data table first but that is millions of rows.

It would also be nice to be able to add a boolean field to each of the final rows that is true when t0.value = t1.value & t0.status = t1.status & t0.connected = t1.connected.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Why the specific datetime filters? You also get random data not necessarily related to the MAX(datetime) since the group by doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: How many channels are you likely to have vs how many data records?

Comment: The specific date_times I put in are random, and will be variables in php code. The number of channels will be much much smaller than the number of data records. There might be on the order of a 100,000 or more channels, but probably millions of data records. Does the group by not return the row corresponding to that maximum date_time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the two sub-queries to one

```
SELECT channel_id,
   MAX(date_time) AS t1_date_time,
   MAX(case when date_time <= {$p1} then date_time end) AS t0_date_time
FROM data
WHERE date_time <= {$p2}
GROUP BY channel_id
```

GROUP BY is notoriously misleading in MySQL. Imagine if you had MIN() and MAX() in the same select, which row should the non-grouped columns come from? Once you understand this, you will see why it is not deterministic.

To get the full t0 and t1 rows

```
SELECT x.channel_id,
       t0.date_time, t0.value, t0.status, t0.connected,
       t1.date_time, t1.value, t1.status, t1.connected
FROM (
    SELECT channel_id,
       MAX(date_time) AS t1_date_time,
       MAX(case when date_time <= {$p1} then date_time end) AS t0_date_time
    FROM data
    WHERE date_time <= {$p2}
    GROUP BY channel_id
) x
INNER JOIN data t1 on t1.channel_id = x.channel_id and t1.date_time = x.t1_date_time
LEFT JOIN data t0 on t0.channel_id = x.channel_id and t0.date_time = x.t0_date_time
```

And finally a join to get the channel name

```
SELECT c.channel_name,
       t0.date_time, t0.value, t0.status, t0.connected,
       t1.date_time, t1.value, t1.status, t1.connected,
       t0.value=t1.value AND t1.status=t0.status
                         AND t0.connected=t1.connected name_me
FROM (
    SELECT channel_id,
       MAX(date_time) AS t1_date_time,
       MAX(case when date_time <= {$p1} then date_time end) AS t0_date_time
    FROM data
    WHERE date_time <= {$p2}
    GROUP BY channel_id
) x
INNER JOIN channels c on c.channel_id = x.channel_id
INNER JOIN data t1 on t1.channel_id = x.channel_id and t1.date_time = x.t1_date_time
LEFT JOIN data t0 on t0.channel_id = x.channel_id and t0.date_time = x.t0_date_time
```

---

#### EDIT

To perform an RLIKE on channel name, it looks simple enough to add a WHERE clause at the end of the query on `c.channel_name`.  It may however perform better to filter it at the subquery, making use of MySQL feature of processing comma-notation joins left to right.

```
SELECT x.channel_name,
       t0.date_time, t0.value, t0.status, t0.connected,
       t1.date_time, t1.value, t1.status, t1.connected,
       t0.value=t1.value AND t1.status=t0.status
                         AND t0.connected=t1.connected name_me
(
    SELECT c.channel_id, c.channel_name,
       MAX(d.date_time) AS t1_date_time,
       MAX(case when d.date_time <= {$p1} then d.date_time end) AS t0_date_time
    FROM channels c, data d
    WHERE c.channel_name RLIKE {$expr}
      AND c.channel_id = d.channel_id
      AND d.date_time <= {$p2}
    GROUP BY c.channel_id
) x
INNER JOIN data t1 on t1.channel_id = x.channel_id and t1.date_time = x.t1_date_time
LEFT JOIN data t0 on t0.channel_id = x.channel_id and t0.date_time = x.t0_date_time
```

Comment: Thank you! What does MAX(case when date_time <= {$p1} then date_time end) do when date_time > {$p1}? The case statement is new to me.

Comment: CASE has a default of `ELSE NULL`. So for all cases where `date_time > $p1`, they are turned into NULLs so the MAX over that range is not considered. Using MAX with case allows the query to complete in one pass instead of two.

Comment: Very nice! Is there an easy way to add a boolean field to each row that is true only when t0.value = t1.value, t0.status = t1.status and t0.connected = t1.connected?

Comment: Thank you again! The only thing I had to change was channel to channels on the first inner join :)

Comment: If I wanted to narrow down the number of channels by a RLIKE on the channel_name, where would be the best place to put it? Is it possible to do that in the group by, so that as few channels are compared as possible?

Comment: Hmmm, strangely this seems to take about twice as long as putting it at the end of the first inner join. I thought that your edit would be the way too. Maybe because it has to do a much larger join on the sub-query from channels, data? I'm running it on 51,171 channels and 18,535,661 data records. Using RLIKE '.*' it takes about 13.5 sec using the WHERE clause on the first INNER JOIN and about 28 sec with it in the sub-query.

Comment: @Patrick - you're right. I forgot about the $date filters, which flips the equation because the distribution changes from 5:1853 (channel:data) to something more in favour of data.  So forcing channel to go first (implicitly by using channel <comma> data instead of INNER JOIN) was a bad idea.